# Sendmail: Mails are still being relayed to root@localhost

Tags: linux, sendmail, smarthost

I am running CENTOS 6.2 with 2 virtual machines one '**auth'(192.168.0.2)** and another **proxy (192.168.0.3)**. Proxy host has no internet connection. 
My intention is proxy host will send its mail to auth host and auth host send the mail out from there.

I have configured the smart host configuration in sendmail.mc in **proxy** as such :

```
define(`SMART_HOST', '192.168.0.2')
```

I also have set up a relay in **auth** under access:

```
CONNECT:192.168.0.3 RELAY
```

However, when I still try to send mail out from proxy using :

```
mail cumaresen@gmail.com
```

The mail is not being sent out and the logs show it as such :

```
Jan 15 01:03:48 test1 sendmail[14388]: s0F8xmdl014388: from=proxy, size=244, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<201401150859.s0F8xmdl014388@test1>, relay=root@localhost
Jan 15 01:03:48 test1 sendmail[14388]: s0F8xmdl014388: to=cumaresen@gmail.com, delay=00:04:00, mailer=esmtp, pri=30244, dsn=4.4.3, stat=queued
```

It is still relaying via root@localhost.

I have tried using the [fix as explained by EreBusBat](https://serverfault.com/questions/215388/how-to-configure-sendmail-to-relay-through-a-specific-server?rq=1) and I still experience the same issue.

Comment: i have dont the necessary recompiles:

i.e:

m4 sendmail.mc > /etc/sendmail.cf

makemap hash access.db < access

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried that and still did not work.

However, I looked around some more and found a solution. What was happening was that 'proxy''s sendmail kept checking with my DNS servers to resolve for the location of 'auth' although it did not have Internet. As such, when it failed it fell back to `root@localhost` as a relay agent.

I needed to force proxy's sendmail to look up my `/etc/hosts` file instead. To do that, I did the following:

In `/etc/mail/submit.mc` file:

```
divert(0)dnl
include(`/usr/share/sendmail-cf/m4/cf.m4')
VERSIONID(`linux setup for RHEL')dnl
define(`confCF_VERSION', `Submit')dnl
define(`__OSTYPE__',`')dnl dirty hack to keep proto.m4 from complaining
define(`confTIME_ZONE', `USE_TZ')dnl
define(`confDONT_INIT_GROUPS', `True')dnl
define(`confPID_FILE', `/var/run/sm-client.pid')dnl
define(`SMART_HOST',`my smarthost from /etc/hosts')dnl
define(`PROCMAIL_MAILER_PATH',`/usr/bin/procmail')dnl
define(`ALIAS_FILE', `/etc/aliases')dnl
MASQUERADE_AS(`Your DNS domain: example.com')dnl
FEATURE(masquerade_envelope)dnl
FEATURE(masquerade_entire_domain)dnl
FEATURE(`use_ct_file')dnl
MAILER(smtp)dnl
MAILER(procmail)dnl
```

Also, create in `/etc/mail` a server.switch file:

hosts   files
aliases files

Credits to: http://www.tenox.net/docs/force2smarthost.html for the solution.

Comment: Could your report what has been recorded in the log files?

Comment: Hi Andrzej, i was able to resolve it. What was reported was that proxy was realying the message to root@localhost

There were no error messages in that case if that is what you were asking about.

Answer (score 1):

Include mailer specification in your smart host definition and put the IP address inside square brackets.

```
define(`SMART_HOST', `relay:[192.168.0.2]')
```